# Remove Outliers in BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data, charts

Is it possible to automatically remove the outliers that are detected by `"Outliers"` within `BoxWhiskerChart`? Somehow `DeleteAnomalies` does not seem always seem to work. Any ideas? Essentially I want to remove the outliers showing with the circle in the figure

[image]

where the data is

```
data1 = {0.4203, 0.1087, 0.1366, 0.2416, 0.6286, 0.7908, 0.7615, 1.2565, \
0.7069, 0.1799, 0.8107, 0.2604, 1.0147, 0.8855, 0.4444, 0.4328, 0.44, \
2.0391, 0.7383, 0.2205, 0.692, 0.3859, 0.192, 0.6309, 0.6164, 0.4937, \
0.803, 0.4569, 0.5222, 0.938, 0.7956, 0.8166, 0.7562, 1.2832, 0.8581}

data2 = {0.2383, 0.3546, 0.8735, 0.6548, 0.5984, 0.4561, 0.8556, 0.7986, \
0.2181, 1.058, 0.9113, 0.4884, 0.1871, 0.3989, 0.238, 1.0243, 0.7271, \
0.3641, 0.3796, 0.3016, 0.2945, 0.4193, 0.724, 0.2771, 0.5613, \
0.7667, 0.9729, 0.3815, 0.4142, 0.7455, 0.8616, 0.5757, 0.5664, \
0.1015, 0.4917, 0.6048, 0.8877, 0.8456, 1.3226, 0.8138, 0.7868, \
1.5958, 0.7256, 0.7353, 0.5801, 0.8084, 0.7004, 0.6247, 0.6765, \
0.8071, 0.9352, 0.4119, 1.2578, 1.756, 0.8905, 0.1325, 0.9153, \
0.4019, 0.368, 0.6376, 0.784, 0.3875, 0.957, 0.6789, 0.948, 0.7024, \
0.7062, 0.2084, 0.4043, 0.745, 0.7742, 0.7769, 0.4801, 0.7978, \
0.9004, 1.1708, 1.3341, 0.7376, 0.585, 0.9648, 0.9191, 0.3436, \
0.5804, 0.735, 1.3176, 0.4748, 0.3699, 1.1614, 0.6834, 1.7399, \
0.6326, 1.8135, 0.4952, 0.4566, 0.7462, 0.7538, 1.3064, 1.248, \
1.3898, 0.3762, 1.0183, 2.4155, 0.7688, 1.4847, 1.3384, 1.0224, \
1.1651, 0.828, 1.5717, 1.5347, 1.867, 0.8935, 1.7056, 1.7457, 1.2412, \
1.0565, 1.2122, 0.8319, 0.9338, 0.8755, 2.0922, 0.7237, 1.1749, \
0.9267, 2.0414, 0.5219, 1.2608, 0.8713, 0.5236, 0.8465, 0.9993, \
0.9411, 0.8427, 0.8958, 0.9941, 0.7128, 0.9855, 0.618, 0.9618, \
1.5467, 1.264, 1.1727, 0.8993, 1.0647, 1.0588, 1.5056, 0.7994, \
0.8144, 0.4243, 1.9144, 0.8388, 1.366, 1.3539, 0.1452, 1.0353, \
1.0128, 1.8411, 0.8006, 1.6407, 1.0436, 1.1651, 1.1901, 2.636, \
0.9189, 1.3148, 0.7694, 0.8565, 0.8105, 0.7932, 1.0582, 1.0828, \
0.9881, 1.6959, 0.8257, 0.5502, 1.1671, 1.6598, 0.4298, 0.6475, \
3.4179, 1.3251, 1.7484, 1.4989, 0.6359, 0.793, 1.5982, 1.3591, 0.339, \
2.3133, 2.147, 1.19, 2.6426, 1.7799, 1.4941, 1.0867, 0.8212, 0.5932, \
0.7318, 1.6003, 1.3919, 0.6235, 1.3959, 1.2471, 0.8678, 1.0173, \
1.1953, 1.3272, 0.9823, 1.2895, 0.5696, 0.7819, 1.6519, 1.7479, \
0.708, 1.1658, 1.3489, 1.5388, 1.3527, 1.2879, 1.1967, 1.0487, \
2.4073, 0.886, 2.2007, 1.0977, 0.9994, 0.522, 0.9271, 3.1344, 1.194, \
1.6859, 1.52, 1.4362, 0.8689, 1.4533, 0.8735, 1.1683, 1.6501, 0.5921, \
2.1358, 1.5373, 1.327, 2.2383, 0.6617, 1.3859, 0.9786, 1.4722, \
1.4891, 0.9931, 0.7015, 1.6651, 1.3637, 1.06, 1.2336, 1.1873, 1.9456, \
1.8313, 3.1359, 1.2111, 1.5379, 1.1171, 1.511, 1.4938, 0.825, 1.0986}
```

Comment: Don’t do it.  I’d call that data tampering.

Comment: @JimB the OP is not asking if it's ethical, or scientifically sound, but how to accomplish a programming task that is not well explained in the documentation. This may not be a well-developed question, but it is on-topic.

Comment: @rhermans Of course the OP was not asking if it was ethical.  It's not ethical: it's data tampering as it is modifying a standard definition of a data display to get rid of inconvenient data.  Those answering should know better.

Comment: @JimB It would be unethical only if the processed data is used to make a false claim. There is in no ethical problem if the procedure is disclosed, or if the use involves no claims. Furthermore, this is a Mathematica programming site, not a puritan *holier than the pope* ethics forum.

Comment: @JimB, while I argee, blindly removing data is not the right approach, it should not be taken to the extreme. Data cleaning is a thing, but should be done with care. Say you want to measure weights of cats, but you got several dogs, will you remove dogs? In my example I've specificaly mixed two distributions.

Comment: @I.M.  I think we are in agreement.  I would hope for an explicit warning in an answer that points out what you stated in your comment and that removing points isn't just to justify an erroneous conclusion.

Comment: @JimB, I've added a note about data cleaning, I would hope you can edit/extend your extreme view comment

Comment: @I.M. Thanks.  I've removed my downvote from your answer and changed it to an upvote.  But in this world there needs to be more concern for ethical issues with making inferences from data (even if the ethical issues are only "potential").

Answer (score 5):

From [Wolfram MathWorld's explanation of Box-and-Whisker Plot](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Box-and-WhiskerPlot.html) outliers are defined as being the data points further than $3/2$ times the [`InterquartileRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterquartileRange.html) from the [`Median`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Median.html).

```
removeoutlier[data_]:=Block[
    {mean, iqr},
    median = Median[data] ;
    iqr   = 3/2*InterquartileRange[data];
    Select[data, ( median -iqr < # < median +iqr )& ]
]
```

Other functions also remove "outliers", for instance, the [`HampelFilter`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HampelFilter), however, this uses a different definition of "outlier".

```
ResourceFunction["HampelFilter"][data2]
```

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Downvote addressed in a comment above.

Comment: @rhermans, your definition of wiskers is wrong, `Mean` is not the right center tendency estimator for data with outliers

Comment: @I.M. I'm clearly stating that I'm using the definition on Wolfram MathWorld about Box-and-Whisker Plot. Is my implementation not what *that* definition states?

Comment: @rhermans, mean is not mentioned in the 1st link

Comment: *"Draw the statistical median M as a horizontal line in the box. Now extend the "whiskers" to the farthest points that are not outliers (i.e., that are within 3/2 times the interquartile range of Q_1 and Q_3)."* You are correct, I should have used `Median` not `Mean`. I stand Corrected. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

(add a note as per JimB's request)

Note, data cleaning should be done with care. Simply removing data outside whiskers, do not guarantee the removed data to be 'true' outliers, i.e. drawn from a different distribution.

see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot)

```
(* generate test data *)
SeedRandom[1] ;
data = Join[
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.5, 0.1], 1000], (* -- true population *)
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2.0, 0.25], 10]   (* -- outliers *)
] ;

(* compute wiskers using 1.5 iqr *)
{q$min, q$max} = Quantile[data, {1/4, 3/4}] ;
iqr = q$max - q$min ;
factor = 1.5 ;
{wisker$min, wisker$max} = {q$min - factor*iqr,  q$max + factor*iqr} ;

(* filter data *)
filtered = Select[data, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{wisker$min, wisker$max}], #] &] ;

(* plot result *)
Show[
    BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", Method->{"BoxRange" -> "Quantile"}] ,
    Graphics[
        {
            Thick,
            Gray,
            InfiniteLine[{{0, Max[filtered]}, {1, Max[filtered]}}],
            InfiniteLine[{{0, Min[filtered]}, {1, Min[filtered]}}],
            Thin, Dashed,
            Red, InfiniteLine[{{0, wisker$min}, {1, wisker$min}}],
            Blue, InfiniteLine[{{0, wisker$max}, {1, wisker$max}}]
        }
    ]
]
```

[image]

Another similar options based on robust dispersion:

```
center = Median[data] ;
spread = Sqrt[BiweightMidvariance[data]] ;
normal = (data - center)/spread ;
factor = 5.0 ;

filtered = Select[normal, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{-factor, factor}], #] &] ;

ListPlot[
    {normal, filtered},
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle->{Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red], Blue},
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My point in the comments (unfortunately not well stated) is not that removing outliers is bad (that can be a good thing) but it is the erasing of the outliers from a box plot of the original data is what is of concern as it can (and will much of the time) result in the wrong box plot for your outlier-removed data.

Consider using @rhermans function to remove potential (repeat: potential) outliers:

```
data1a = removeoutlier[data1];
data2a = removeoutlier[data2];
```

Now look at the box plots with and without the outliers:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{data1, data1a}, "Outliers", 
 ChartLabels -> {"data1", "data1 with\noutliers removed"}]

BoxWhiskerChart[{data2, data2a}, "Outliers", 
 ChartLabels -> {"data2", "data2 with\noutliers removed"}]
```

[image: Box plots for data1 with and without outliers]

[image: Box plots for data2 with and without outliers]

One sees that just erasing the outliers from the original boxplot does not result in the same box plot as with the outliers removed.  (And, of course, one needs to describe the potential outlier discovery method and the subsequent rationale for tossing any data.)

Comment: It's nice to hear from different perspectives and I appreciate your effort. Even though it might not be in the domain of the question, since you point out this subtle detail, I think showing alternatives such as `BoxWhiskerChart[data2,"Outliers"]/.Inset[Style["\[FilledSmallCircle]",___], ___]->Nothing` would also be helpful (exclude vs hide).

Comment: @BenIzd  Thanks.  I was certainly a bit harsh with my initial comments as I immediately went to "hide" rather than "exclude".  But I've seen a lot of this in my career as a statistician.  Most folks are completely innocent of wrong doing but even the appearance "hiding data" does set me off.  And using subject-matter-free algorithms to exclude outliers is a close second.  (To get a list of potential outliers, no problem.  The problem is when the potential outliers are not checked against subject-matter knowledge.)

Comment: @BenIzd  I assume your example in your comment is showing "how to hide outliers" as opposed to "how to eliminate outliers" ?  Also, if I asked a physics-related question here and it was full of holes, I would hope that someone would call me out on that.  So "outside of *Mathematica* expertise" should be welcomed.

Comment: Yes, the code is for hiding (which probably is not requested). I 100% agree with "outside of Mathematica expertise", we can find the code here and there but what is rare, is these experiences that are built over many years.

Comment: @BenIzd It's the "hiding" that causes me concern.  My examples above shows that one gets the wrong boxplot when you do that.

Comment: I think my definition is the opposite or I misunderstand something. Hide as be in the computation but not visible in the graph, exclude as not in the computation nor in the graph (I should also mention I just recently take steps in the path you probably reached miles, so there would be many lessons to learn).

Comment: @BenIzd The kind of "hiding" I'm talking about is the removal of items from a figure generated by a graphical function.  I claim the order of events should be (1) remove "outliers", (2) Produce figure rather than (2) then (1).  It's what I would call "defacing" a figure.  And adding things to a figure that would appear to change the meaning of the original figure is also of similar badness.  One example is "ShaprieGate" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Dorian%E2%80%93Alabama_controversy).